# Lightning Component JS controller call one method from other method without helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How to call Lightning Component JS controller call one method from other method without helper

```
selectOther: function(component, event, helper) {
       //Call fetchAddress
},
fetchAddress: function(component, event, helper) {
       console.log('---fetchAddress');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
selectOther: function(component, event, helper) {
   var fethAddress = component.get('c.fetchAddress');
   $A.enqueueAction(fethAddress);
},
fetchAddress: function(component, event, helper) {
   console.log('---fetchAddress');
}
```